# Why does tm_mday start from 1 while all other elements of struct tm start from 0?

Tags: c, time, struct, mktime

While [answering another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31380257/520162), I told the OP he needs to initialize his `struct tm` variable correctly but needs to be careful because he couldn't simply use

```
struct tm mytime;
memset(&mytime, 0, sizeof(mytime));
```

because *not all* fields of `struct tm` are valid from `0`. [A closer look on `struct tm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html) showed me that it is exactly **one** field of `struct tm` that doesn't have `0` as valid value, namely `tm_mday`:

> ```
> int    tm_sec   seconds [0,61]
> int    tm_min   minutes [0,59]
> int    tm_hour  hour [0,23]
> int    tm_mday  day of month [1,31]
> int    tm_mon   month of year [0,11]
> int    tm_year  years since 1900
> int    tm_wday  day of week [0,6] (Sunday = 0)
> int    tm_yday  day of year [0,365]
> int    tm_isdst daylight savings flag
> ```

Why? What were the thoughts behind the decision that for this very element, `0` shall be no valid value???

Comment: `tm_year` starts from 1 too (there's no year 'zero'), it is just reduced by 1900, which may mask the lack of zero. ;) Generally all values have ranges which best fit either the direct display (hours .. seconds) or indexing string arrays (months).

Comment: @CiaPan: `indexing string arrays` sounds very reasonable, however, there's no string-indexing for `tm_yday` where `0` is valid.

Comment: @CiaPan A `tm_year` of zero is fine: it means the year `1900`.

Comment: I don't know whether it's part of the rationale, but if `tm_mday` starts from 1, to find next/previous Sunday, you simply have to do `tm_mday - tm_wday` (and ±7), etc., so it allows for relatively "clean" formulas.

Comment: Also, methods for [Computus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus#Week_table:_Julian_and_Gregorian_calendars), arguably earlier than the first `struct tm` definition, use the same convention.

Comment: Just some guess. There is fixed conversion for seconds, minutes, hours, months,years, but not for days. E.g. 1m = 60s; 1h = 60m;  1month = ??? day; 1y = 12m.So, you may use `mod` to  s/m/h/y , such `x mod 60s ` , 'x mod 60m', 'x mod 60h',`x mod 12m`, which will probably produce `0`s,`0`m,`0`h result. But we will not  apply `mod` to day, such as `x mod ??? day`(base is 30 ?31 ? or 29 ?).

Answer (score 5):

It makes sense if you assume the following two rules:

- Store the value starting from 1 if that allows for easiest display without having to add or subtract one in common date formats
- In all other cases (or when the first rule could go either way depending on the format), store the value starting from 0

Applying the rule:

- `tm_sec`, `tm_min`, `tm_hour` displayed starting from 0 so store starting from 0. In 12-hour format the first hour is 12, but the rest can be displayed "as-is" by starting from 0.
- `tm_mday` displayed starting from 1 so store starting from 1
- `tm_mon` displayed starting from 1 in dates like 24/02/1964, but also makes sense to store starting from 0 for ease of indexing strings in an array for dates like 24th February 1964, so could go either way -> start from 0
- `tm_year` 20th century years can be displayed as-is in 2 year format e.g. 24/02/64, or else add 1900, no case where starting from 1 makes sense
- `tm_wday` Usually displayed by indexing a string array, start from 0
- `tm_yday` No clear reason to start from 1 for ease of display, start from 0

So `tm_mday` is the only case where there is a clear advantage to storing it starting from 1 for ease of display in all common cases.

The reference implementation of `asctime` from the [C-89 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.12.3.1) is consistent with this, the only adjustment to any of the values being to add 1900 to `tm_year`:

```
     char *asctime(const struct tm *timeptr)
     {
         static const char wday_name[7][3] = {
                  "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"
         };
         static const char mon_name[12][3] = {
                  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
         };
         static char result[26];

         sprintf(result, "%.3s %.3s%3d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d %d\n",
                  wday_name[timeptr->tm_wday],
                  mon_name[timeptr->tm_mon],
                  timeptr->tm_mday, timeptr->tm_hour,
                  timeptr->tm_min, timeptr->tm_sec,
                  1900 + timeptr->tm_year);
         return result;
     }
```

Comment: The reasoning for `tm_mon` is not convincing; you could all other things in an array too. And `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` do not follow the "rule 1" either.

Comment: @BlueMoon There is no clear reason for why tm_wday and tm_yday would be easier to display if they were stored starting from 1, so rule 1 fits IMO.

Comment: "tm_mday displayed starting from 1 so store starting from 1"  Seems that would apply to tm_yday as well.

Comment: @Scooter, the day of the year isn't used in any common date display formats, so the rationale isn't as compelling as for the day of the month, which is.

Comment: Hmmm `static char result[26]; sprintf(result, "%.3s %.3s%3d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d %d\n",` ripe for exploits with fields with large values.  Hacker concern was not so high then versus byte cost.

Comment: I don't find that very convincing. Most of the time you would show the month as a number, e.g. `2018-03-19` or `19.3.2018` or `3/19/2018`; thus you would have to add 1 everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the babylonians decided to use number `1` for the first day in a month (for quite obvious reasons) because they hadn't invented number `0` yet.

(Same reason for year 1 being the first year AC)

Since then no one changed the numbering of months.

Comment: But then why is `tm_mon` starting at 0 and not at 1 ??

Comment: @MichaelWalz: See the comment of CiaPan above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380566/why-does-tm-mday-start-from-1-while-all-other-elements-of-struct-tm-start-from-0/31380773#comment50739357_31380566). Indexing string arrays may be an explanation here...

Comment: Well the first month is called "January", not "0" or "1", so you need a lookup table anyway. And this table is most naturally indexed with an integer starting at 0 in C.

Comment: @eckes But zero _is_ valid for `tm_year`. And if `tm_mday` starts from `1` because it "doesn't need to index a string array", then why doesn't `tm_yday` start from `1`?

Comment: @DrKoch For fun: Over-simplification: the 10th month _was_ Dec-ember, 9th Nov-ember, 8th Oct-ober and 7th Sept-ember and started the year in March and all that leap-year junk was in the last month February.  Then the politicians got involved.  Julius Caesar sorted it out and was assassinated the next year.  That is what one gets for fixing the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason is that the `tm_mday == 0` check can be used to treat such a date as a "null date" (or "not set" / "not available"), while retaining the ability to implicitly set variables of `struct tm` type to that state by zero-initialization semantics, which is not possible if some non-zero value (say, `INT_MIN`) is being used instead for this purpose.